# Tag meta viewport

Tags: android, html, css, viewport

I'm trying to make web site with vieport equal 1400px. But when I increase viewport width from 1265px to 1400px it makes horizontal scroll on phone broowser. Is it possible to make viewport bigger than 1280px without hotizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Are you using the viewport meta tag? If your site is not responsive, then it may be better not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1400">
```

Comment: Yes, but this not work. This cause hotrizontal scroll appear but not paddings from left and right. And my question is why is that happen? I need free spase left and right from content of page.

Comment: Post an demo of your layout, then. Otherwise, we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: Here [link](http://107.170.150.242/laura/test.html). I need whole block content to show on phones, with paddings. But instead horizontal scroll apears.

Comment: On my phone I only get a tiny bit of scrolling, probably because of the default padding on the body element. Try this: `body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Comment: I tried but it's not work. Scroll is because of viewport width bigger than 1280px. It's strange behavior.

Comment: What is your phone? Works fine on iPhone.

Comment: Android. I'll test on iphone.